# build a wxPython wx.Icon from a resource file

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython application and I load an icon on the main form in the code like below

```
        icon = wx.Icon()
        icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("icons/sm.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
        # icon.LoadFile("icons/sm.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.SetIcon(icon)
```

This works in the python code when running in the development environment, where I have a `icons/` folder that contains the `sm.ico` file, but when I package it up, the final exe cannot find "icons/sm.ico".

So, I tried to put this ico file into a resource file, so I built the following qrc file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>icons/sm.ico</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then, I use the pyrcc5.exe command to convert it to a python file (e.g. sm_rc.py), but I don't know how to load the ico image from that resource file. I tried 'LoadFile' as below, didn't work:

```
import src.ui.sm_rc
icon.LoadFile("icons/sm.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
```

So, the fundamental question is how to build a resource file that wxPython can read image from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel.
`wxpython` has a facility for incorporating `png` images into a python module.
You may then access them as an image, a bitmap or an icon.

https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.tools.img2py.html#module-wx.tools.img2py

Here is the code I use in a Linux project, adapt as necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm fs_images.py
touch fs_images.py
img2py -n footswitch24 -c -i -f ../footswitch24.png fs_images.py
img2py -a -n footswitch24HiVis -c -i -f ../footswitch24HiVis.png fs_images.py
img2py -a -n footswitch24HiVisB -c -i -f ../footswitch24HiVisB.png fs_images.py
img2py -a -n footswitch24HiVisY -c -i -f ../footswitch24HiVisY.png fs_images.py
for image in *.png
do
 short=$(echo "$image" | awk -F'.' '{print $1}')
 img2py -a -n $short -c -f $image fs_images.py
done
cp fs_images.py ../
```

In your code, `import fs_images` then access the images with:

```
self.pause = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel3, -1, size=pb_size, bitmap=fs_images.getpauseBitmap())
```

or for the `ico`:

```
self.ico = fs_images.getfootswitch24Icon()
self.SetIcon(self.ico)
```

Voila! No more missing image files, you wrap the whole lot up in a single python module.

Comment: I used the PyQt way of generating resource file and access. This is the equivalent approach in wxPython application, which worked out great in my wxPython project.